# HTTP POST request to Nodejs service with upload file goes ERR after 8-15 seconds on FF, and 25 seconds Chrome

Tags: node.js, angular, http, express, file-upload

Web app is on **Angular 7**. I'm trying to send larger file to Nodejs service. Smaller files like 3mb are sent correctly but bigger like 20mb are sending and the request is cut. On Chrome I got

> 'ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED'

after each 25 seconds, on Firefox I got error randomly 8-16 seconds and the error is

> "connection wasn't secure"

.
Connection is on valid HTTPS certificate.

On nodejs side the limit with requests are set to 100mb.

Anyone have and idea how to solve the problem with cut requests ?

//nodejs limit

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '100mb'}));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '100mb', extended: true}));
```

//angular

I'm creating  FormData and send file with this.http.post call.

Comment: maybe the request is timing out chek this
https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/http.html#http_server_settimeout_msecs_callback

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to use node streams instead of sending a huge file in one.

Here is a link to the documentation: 
https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html